# Jenkins git several repos trigger

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a project in GitHub with two repositories and dependencies between them.

In Jenkins I have created a job where I specify both repos (I use the *Multiple SCMs* plugin) and I have specified that the build trigger to be a push to GitHub (to any of those repos).

My question is: is there any way Jenkins can know which repo has been pushed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can create two 'dummy' jobs that will trigger the job you created. each one will check only 1 github repository - and you can add a parameter for the changed repo.

Thanks